# Как сделать трансляцию с своего компа на свой сайт?

Tags: веб-программирование

Объясните пожалуйста. Как можно сделать трансляцию своего рабочего стола или своей веб камеры на свой сайт без сторонних сервисов.

Comment: Чем сторонние сервисы не угодили?

Comment: @andreymal не хочу быть зависимым от сторонних сервисов.

Comment: [Первая ссылка из гугла](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858936/html5-live-streaming)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону RMTP сервера. К сожалению, вопрос слишком общий, чтобы дать более подробный ответ.